# How to hide herokuapp.com site built in Django when the site is live

Tags: python, django, heroku

Let's say we have an app in Django (python environment)

```
example.herokuapp.com
```

and we put the site live

```
example.com
```

how to achieve that the site is not accessible via

```
example.herokuapp.com
```

I do not want anyone to access it that way in case someone would be trying to.

Is there a way?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: That won't help me, when you put the site live, the site is accessible via example.com and example.herokuapp.com both. I found the answer already, set the ALLOWED_HOSTS=['example.com'] and it works. Thank you for help, sorry that I have opened this ticket, that the answer is so trivial.

Comment: You should post that as an answer

Comment: ok thank you @dan-klasson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hide

```
example.herokuapp.com
```

from the django live site

```
example.com
```

set

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['example.com']
```

For polishing the website to the top detail, create beautiful custom 500.html template.